# Understanding the rational behind ORDER BY in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works

`SELECT score, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC)  AS 'rank' FROM Scores`

But when I do the following below it doesn't work

`SELECT score, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC)  AS 'rank' FROM Scores ORDER BY rank`

Comment: and what does "not work" mean?

Comment: rank is a reserved word from version 8 so I expect you have a syntax error?

Comment: You are attempting to order by a function name - rank. It works in the first query because you qualified it (probably actually with backticks, not single quotes).  Just don't alias objects using reserved words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RANK is a reserved keyword in MySQL 8.0, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

In your ORDER BY clause, the parser thinks you are using the RANK function, and it gets confused when it reaches the end and finds you have not put `()` after the function name RANK. The error shows what follows the point where it got confused, which is the end of the query, so what follows is `''`.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

You can fix this and use reserved keywords as identifiers by enclosing them in back-ticks:

```
SELECT score, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC)  AS 'rank' 
FROM Scores 
ORDER BY `rank`;
```